# Can I devolve my Mega Pokemon during a battle?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I already have 4 Pokémon capable of Mega Evolution: a Lucario, a Blastoise, a Blaziken and an Ampharos.

However, when I activate Mega Evolution for one of them, then switch out my Pokémon, the button for Mega Evolution is greyed out (inactive).

I understand that for balancing purposes, you shouldn't be able to fight with multiple Mega Evolved Pokémon simultaneously, but is there a way to reset Mega Evolution in order to Mega Evolve another Pokémon while still in combat?

Comment: "Tortoise"? Do you mean Blastoise?

Comment: @StrixVaria Yes, that's it. Shame on me for forgetting the name of my favourite water type Pokémon...

Comment: Think about it this way you get the bonus of your mega and kill one pokemon but lose half your health would it makes sense to be able to devolve and then get the another boost on another pokemon.  That would unbalance any team that can't OHKO your mega pokekmon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can only Mega Evolve one pokemon per battle.

http://www.serebii.net/xy/megaevolutions.shtml